# On Windows command line, Git keeps prompting for credentials

Tags: windows, git

I am on Windws 10, I cloned my Git repository using Https, then I checked in *.git-credentials* that this line is stored:

```
https://my_username:my_password@github.com
```

Also ".gitconfig" files contains:

```
[user]
    email = my_mail
    name = my_name
[init]
    defaultBranch = main
[credential]
    helper = store
```

Both files are on *C:\Users\My_username*

But everytime I try to push (*git push*), it keeps prompting for credentials.

Any idea of what to do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Control Panel/User Accounts/Manage your credentials (top left)/Windows Credentials.  You should have an entry like below for git:https://github.com, and it probably has the wrong password.  This has happened for me.  The Git tools try to create this entry when you push, but can get confused if the wrong password is in there.  If you delete the entry and do a `git push` it should ask for credentials, commit, and then recreate a correct token in the repository, after which it shouldn't ask you for credentials again.

[image]